# Python: Iteratively Writing to Excel Files

Tags: python, excel

Python 2.7. I'm using xlsxwriter.

Let's say I have `myDict = {1: 'One', 2: 'Two', 3: 'Three'}`

I need to perform some transformation on the value and write the result to a spreadsheet.

So I write a function to create a new file and put some headers in there and do formatting, but don't close it so I can write further with my next function.

Then I write another function for transforming my dict values and writing them to the worksheet.

I'm a noob when it comes to classes so please forgive me if this looks silly.

```
import xlsxwriter

class ReadWriteSpreadsheet(object):
    def __init__(self, outputFile=None, writeWorkbook=None,     writeWorksheet=None):
        self.outputFile = outputFile
        self.writeWorksheet = writeWorksheet
        self.writeWorkbook = writeWorkbook

    # This function works fine
    def setup_new_spreadsheet(self):
        self.writeWorkbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(self.outputFile)
        self.writeWorksheet = self.writeWorkbook.add_worksheet('My Worksheet')
        self.writeWorksheet.write('A1', 'TEST') 

    # This one does not
    def write_data(self):
        # Forget iterating through the dict for now
        self.writeWorksheet.write('A5', myDict[1])

x = ReadWriteSpreadsheet(outputFile='test.xlsx')
x.setup_new_spreadsheet()
x.write_data()
```

I get:

```
Exception Exception: Exception('Exception caught in workbook destructor. Explicit close() may be required for workbook.',) in <bound method Workbook.__del__ of <xlsxwriter.workbook.Workbook object at 0x00000000023FDF28>> ignored
```

The docs say this error is due to not closing the workbook, but if I close it then I can't write to it further...

How do I structure this class so that the workbook and worksheet from `setup_new_spreadsheet()` is able to be written to by `write_data()`?

Comment: What do you mean *"does not [work]"*? Error messages? Unexpected outputs? Did you ensure `setup_new_spreadsheet` got called before `write_data`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry I added details about the Type error. And yes, I'm calling the functions in order.

Comment: Evidently `self.writeWorkbook.add_worksheet` doesn't return anything. Perhaps you should look at the library's documentation?

Comment: So many misconceptions in that short piece o' code. I'd recommend to first tackle some OOP and Python basics, before trying to write Excel files.

Comment: @famousgarkin Writing to an excel file in and of itself is not hard. Performing some function involving a write and then performing a subsequent write in a different function without closing the workbook in the first function apparently is.

Comment: @AutomaticStatic: No, famousgarkin is right. You have numerous issues in the code that you've posted. If you think writing to Excel is not hard (and that's a fair assessment, certainly for anyone fluent with XlsxWriter) then you should consider not using a class at all, but just using functions and global variables instead. Some academic types won't like it, but it will be easier to understand and easier to get right for a newbie.

Comment: If you want to be able to close the Excel file, reopen and update as you wish, you could use Pywin32 to drive Excel directly (using COM), with more or less the same fine control as with VBA.

Comment: @JohnY I tried making the workbook and worksheet variables global, but any function that tries to write to the global worksheet returns the same error as that in my OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception mentioned in your question is triggered when python realises you will not need to use your Workbook any more in the rest of your code and therefore decides to delete it from his memory (garbage collection). When doing so, it will realise you haven't closed your workbook yet and so will not have persisted your excel spreadsheet at all on the disk (only happen on close I assume) and will raise that exception.

If you had another method close on your class that did: self.writeWorkbook.close() and made sure to call it last you would not have that error.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `ReadWriteSpreadsheet()` you get a new *instance* of the class you've defined.  That new instance doesn't have any knowledge of any workbooks that were set up in a different instance.

It looks like what you want to do is get a single instance, and then issue the methods on that one instance:

```
x = ReadWriteSpreadsheet(outputFile='test.xlsx')
x.setup_new_spreadsheet()
x.write_data()
```

To address your new concern:

*The docs say this error is due to not closing the workbook, but if I close it then I can't write to it further...*

Yes, that's true, you can't write to it further. That is one of the fundamental properties of Excel files. At the level we're working with here, there's no such thing as "appending" or "updating" an Excel file. Even the Excel program itself cannot do it. You only have two viable approaches:

1. Keep all data in memory and only commit to disk at the very end.
2. Reopen the file, reading the data into memory; modify the in-memory data; and write *all* the in-memory data back out to a new disk file (which can have the same name as the original if you want to overwrite).

The second approach requires using a package that can read Excel files. The main choices there are [`xlrd`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) and [`OpenPyXL`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl). The latter will handle both reading and writing, so if you use that one, you don't need `XlsxWriter`.

Comment: That makes sense, but when I try it, I get `TypeError: 'Worksheet' object is not callable
Exception Exception: Exception('Exception caught in workbook destructor. Explicit close() may be required for workbook.',) in <bound method Workbook.__del__ of <xlsxwriter.workbook.Workbook object at 0x00000000023ADF60>> ignored` 

The docs say you get this error when you don't close the workbook, but  once I close it, I can't write to it further.

Comment: Well, the function that you say works (`setup_new_spreadsheet`) shouldn't work as written in your question, because indeed, `Worksheet` objects are not callable, and yet you're trying to call it. Instead of `self.writeWorksheet('A1', 'TEST')` what you might mean is `self.writeWorksheet.write('A1', 'TEST')`. You also have an obvious indentation error in your `__init__`. So the first thing you need to do if you want any meaningful answers here is to clean up your question so that it really reflects the code you are using.

Comment: Sorry. That was merely a typo in my OP.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry for my sloppy OP, which now matches exactly my code and error message.

Comment: @AutomaticStatic: Your latest edit attempts to use my answer, but you've still got it wrong. Notice the doubled-up periods in the last line.

Comment: So the gist of your updated answer is that I basically need to do all write operations in the function in which I create the new workbook?

Comment: @AutomaticStatic: Not at all. You just have to be sure to *not close* the workbook until you're *really* done with it (using approach 1, which is by far the easier and more efficient way). But you also *do* have to close it at some point. Maybe your mental block is that you're thinking of the `Worksheet.write` method as writing to disk. It's not. Well, technically it sort of can be, but for purposes of your mental model, you really should think of it as writing to an in-memory representation of the worksheet.

Comment: I actually understand that part and that's precisely why I'm confused. My function that creates the new workbook does not close it, so I don't understand why calling a subsequent function to do more writes to the same open workbook is generating this error, which says I need to close it, in which case I can't write to it further. It's very kafkaesque.

Comment: You never said calling a subsequent function with more writes gives you that error. You just regurgitated my code and said "I get: [this error]". So for all we know, you just let the program end at that point, and since the workbook isn't closed, you get that error. That's why I said you DO have to close the workbook AT SOME POINT. Now, if you truly just ran the code, exactly as shown and without any other code, then you should have gotten another error as well (myDict isn't defined). You need to tell us everything if you can't figure this out for yourself.